# AS3: Change TextField Text on multiple instances of the same MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a `MovieClip` called **"number"** in the library. I need to add multiple instances of that MovieClip to stage. Instances should be called `number1`, `number2`,`number3`...and each one needs to have different text inside it.

Is it possible to do this without code, just using flash interface tools? If not, could someone help me with coding that?

Thanks!

Comment: Drag and drop three instances from your library, and give each an instance name in their properties.

Comment: If you really don't want to code,  you can just create a base MovieClip that contains everything BUT the text,  then create individual new movie clips that have the base one on a layer underneath the text fields.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  If so, it would good for your to either accept an answer, or create an answer of your own so there is closure to this question.

Answer (score 1):

For an Class linked `MyNumber` containing a text field named `output`:

```
const N:int = 3; // 3 instances
const TEXTS:Array = ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3']; // 3 texts
var n:MyNumber;

for (var i:int = 0; i < N; i++) {
    n = new MyNumber();
    n.y = 50 * i;
    n.output.text = TEXTS[i];
    this.addChild(n);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without coding, just using flash tools and changing movieclip's parameters?

Comment: @exiibeat - You need to use code if you want to give different values to your text fields. Otherwise you can create 3 movieClips with their different texts and put them on your scene, but it's a poor solution if you just have to change that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use code - at least a little bit.

In addition to **@helloflash**'s answer, here is a simpler solution (with some caveats described below).

On your movieClip, make your text box dynamic, and give it an instance name of `txt` (or whatever you'd like).  Then, put the following line of code on the first frame of your movieClips's timeline:

```
txt.text = this.name;  //works if your text is a simple word with no spaces/puntuaction/symbols and doesn't match any actionscript keywords
```

This will set the text to whatever the instance name of each movieClip is.  Will work great if you text is something simple like "Hello" or "Player1".

---

Now, if you're text is a number (or starts with one), or your text matches a keyword or already defined variable (like this/continue/function/break/stop/play etc), you'll need make it a bit more complicated, something like this:

```
txt.text = this.name.replace("$MC_","");
```

Then give your instance name in this format:  **$MC_stop**,  the code will strip out the `$MC_` part and show the rest. so the text field would be "stop".

---

Now, if you want to include spaces, or most symbols  (dollar sign, underscore and dash I think are the only supported ones), you'll have to add a replace for each one and create a place holder for that character.

So if your text was "**This is my text**", you should give it an instance name of `this_is_my_text" and this should be the code:

```
txt.text = this.name.replace("_"," "); //replace all underscores with space
```

Add as many replace statements for as many characters you need.

So, if you text was "**1. This is my text!!!**" - The instance name could be: `$MC_1$dot_This_is_my_text$ex$ex$ex` and the code:

```
txt.text = this.name.replace("$MC_","").replace("_"," ").replace("$dot",".").replace("$ex","!"); //you can keep chaining on as many replace statements as you need.
```

Of course, at this point you might as well just use full on code like @helloflash's answer. But if you text isn't that complicated, this may be a good solution for you.

Comment: @exiibeat - If you found it useful, feel free to indicate so with an upvote.   Also, if one of the answers lead to your solution, please accept it, if not, you can create your own answer and accept that.